# Plotting and calculating mid price and weightet mid-price

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with my code - Somehow it keeps giving me a keyerror: "None of [Float]...."

I need to calculate: P_mid = P_offer+P_bid/2

and

volume weightet mid_price = VWMP = (P_bid * Size_offer)+(P_offer * Size_bid)/Size_Offer+Size_Bid

So far my code looks like this:

```
    import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nasdaq_1 = pd.read_csv (r'Path to csv')

np.array(nasdaq_1)
#print(nasdaq_1)

mid_price = (np.array(nasdaq_1.Offer_Price) + np.array(nasdaq_1.Bid_Price))/2
#print(mid_price)

weightet_mid_price = (np.array(nasdaq_1.Offer_Price)*np.array(nasdaq_1.Bid_Size) + np.array(nasdaq_1.Bid_Price)*np.array(nasdaq_1.Offer_Size))/(np.array(nasdaq_1.Offer_Size)+np.array(nasdaq_1.Bid_Size))
print(weightet_mid_price)

nasdaq_1[mid_price].plot()

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot(nasdaq_1.index, nasdaq_1[mid_price])
plt.xlabel("Datetime")
plt.ylabel("$ price")
plt.title("Mid-price between bid and offer prices")
```

All help is highly appreciated!!

CSV data sample:

|DateTime,Time,Exchange,Symbol,Bid_Price,Bid_Size,Offer_Price,Offer_Size
|2017-01-03 09:30:00,93000766290000.0,T,PFE,32.55,8.0,32.76,8.0
|2017-01-03 09:30:01,93001992610000.0,T,PFE,32.67,8.0,32.7,31.0
|2017-01-03 09:30:02,93002933311000.0,T,PFE,32.67,7.0,32.7,2.0
|2017-01-03 09:30:03,93003882764000.0,T,PFE,32.7,1.0,32.76,17.0
|2017-01-03 09:30:04,93004943608000.0,T,PFE,32.7,1.0,32.73,13.0
|2017-01-03 09:30:05,93005991747000.0,T,PFE,32.69,2.0,32.74,41.0
|2017-01-03 09:30:06,93006506218000.0,T,PFE,32.67,5.0,32.74,41.0

Image shows the data I am using. Screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Please modify your source code to create enough dataframe to reproduce your problem. It is hard for us to re-create it from image.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to plot? It seems that you are computing `weightet_mid_price`; but not using it anywhere. What is your expected output?

Comment: Hi Azhar,
Should I attach the CSV file I'm using?
I haven't plottet the weightet_mid_price yet, as it returns an error when I am trying to plot the mid_price

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to cast the data frame columns into numpy arrays for your calculations.

The error you see is due to the line `nasdaq_1[mid_price].plot()`.
`df[x]` expects `x` to be either a column name or a list/array of columns. You are passing a numpy array with entries which cannot be found.

Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io

s = io.StringIO("""DateTime,Time,Exchange,Symbol,Bid_Price,Bid_Size,Offer_Price,Offer_Size
2017-01-03 09:30:00,93000766290000.0,T,PFE,32.55,8.0,32.76,8.0
2017-01-03 09:30:01,93001992610000.0,T,PFE,32.67,8.0,32.7,31.0
2017-01-03 09:30:02,93002933311000.0,T,PFE,32.67,7.0,32.7,2.0
2017-01-03 09:30:03,93003882764000.0,T,PFE,32.7,1.0,32.76,17.0
2017-01-03 09:30:04,93004943608000.0,T,PFE,32.7,1.0,32.73,13.0
2017-01-03 09:30:05,93005991747000.0,T,PFE,32.69,2.0,32.74,41.0
2017-01-03 09:30:06,93006506218000.0,T,PFE,32.67,5.0,32.74,41.0
""")


nasdaq_1 = pd.read_csv(s, parse_dates=['DateTime'])

mid_price = (nasdaq_1["Offer_Price"] + nasdaq_1["Bid_Price"])/2

weightet_mid_price = (
    (nasdaq_1["Offer_Price"]*nasdaq_1["Bid_Size"] + nasdaq_1["Bid_Price"]*nasdaq_1["Offer_Size"])
    / (nasdaq_1["Offer_Size"] + nasdaq_1["Bid_Size"])
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.plot(nasdaq_1["DateTime"], mid_price)
ax.set_xlabel("Datetime")
ax.set_ylabel("$ price")
ax.set_title("Mid-price between bid and offer prices")
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Edit:
Parse the DateTime column to make it datetime values instead of strings.